# Blazor Server App remove margin between MainLayout.razor and Index.razor

Tags: css, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

After I customised the MainLayout.razor file and the Index.razor file I'm not able to remove a white space between the two views.

I tried inserting style="margin:0px" everywhere but nothing.
I've looked for alternatives but I couldn't solve it, or rather I couldn't find any other solution that would allow me to understand how it works.

MainLayout.razor

@inherits LayoutComponentBase

```
    <style>
        .resLogo {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 150px;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
                <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
                    <LoginDisplay />
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin:0px;>
                    <div class="col" />
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img class="resLogo" src="img/logo.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <p style="font-size:1vw">text1</p>
                        <p style="font-size:1vw">text2</p>
                        <p style="font-size:3vw">text3</p>
                        <p style="font-size:2vw">text4</p>
                        <p style="font-size:1.5vw">text5</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col" />
                </div>
                <div class="content" style="margin:0px">
                    @Body
                </div>
                <div>
                    This is the footer
                </div>
```

Index.razor

@page "/"

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" />
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            index slider container
        </div>
        <div class="col" />
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is really hard to say what can be a reason of undesired margin without reproduced example, however give a try to [Bootstrap spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/) such as `mt-0` or `mb-0`.

So code could look like this:

```
<div class="content mt-0 mb-0">
    @Body
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="row mt-0 mb-0">
    <div class="col" />
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        index slider container
    </div>
    <div class="col" />
</div>
```

Or if you want to remove all margins, then you can use `m-0` class. Moreover, if you want to remove padding, then feel free to use `p-0` class of Bootstrap.

**UPDATE:**

It looks like `p` has extra values for margin. So it creates extra space between div. So you can override it through new rule:

```
div > p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[An example where there is no line with color `burlywood`.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kqsuqD)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately nothing has changed.
Does the reproducibility of the example depend on me?

Comment: @undertree sure you can create reproduced example  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mobile?id=CsMvc

Comment: Thank you again, I didn't yet use it... really helpful. In the frame view you can see the line dividing the red background (layout) from the black background (index).

However, if you switch to the full screen view, the index seems to overlap the layout.

I haven't noticed this yet because when I run locally I get a view like the one in the box.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RIil8n

What I would like to achieve is something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/6v3bqne8/

Comment: @undertree where is margin gap between layout and body? Could you show at the image?

Comment: could you send me an example? Even if I delete all the <p> tags, the space persists.

Comment: @undertree please, see my updated answer. I've added an example with jsfiddle where there is no undesired space with `burlywood` color

Comment: I have updated by inserting the image from your example. There are a few things wrong with it:
- the body div (red) overlaps the image and text divs (blak), consequently the parent div (burlywood).
- summary for the declaration of the columns in order from left to right for the first row:
col;
col-sm-2;
col-sm-8;
col;
and for the second row
col;
col-sm-10;
col;
This should create two empty columns of equal size on the left and right, and the rows should be horizontally aligned.

Comment: I really appreciate your commitment to help me. However, I cannot accept your answer as solving the problem and I regret that.

In fact the space has been eliminated. However, if this means that the divs are overlapping or misaligned, it seems normal to me that this is not a usable solution for me or for other users. Again, thank you very much, also for your understanding.